# How do I convert a decimal to an int in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, int, decimal

How do I convert a decimal to an int?

Comment: It would be helpful to know whether you wanted to round to the nearest int or just drop the numbers after the decimal (ie: always round down)

Answer (score 323):

Use `Convert.ToInt32` from `mscorlib` as in

```
decimal value = 3.14m;
int n = Convert.ToInt32(value);
```

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/93kx4xke.aspx). You can also use `Decimal.ToInt32`. Again, see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.toint32.aspx). Finally, you can do a direct cast as in

```
decimal value = 3.14m;
int n = (int) value;
```

which uses the explicit cast operator. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zf02hx8s.aspx).

Comment: Watch out: Convert has some surprising behaviour for certain conversion (`null` vs. `0` vs. `""`).  I'd recommend never using Convert unless you absolutely need its flexibility (i.e. in dynamically typed scenarios)

Comment: -1 since this will not work for values such as decimal.MaxValue and decimal.MinValue and results in an `OverflowException`. I believe that @Will provides a better answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/501165/39532

Comment: Be careful, because `Convert.ToInt32` and `Decimal.ToInt32` behave differently. From MSDN: `Decimal.ToInt32` - The return value is the integral part of the decimal value; fractional digits are **truncated**. `Convert.ToInt32` - Return value **rounded** to the nearest 32-bit signed integer. If value is halfway between two whole numbers, the even number is returned; that is, 4.5 is converted to 4, and 5.5 is converted to 6.

Answer (score 69):

You can't.

Well, of course you *could*, however an int (System.Int32) is not big enough to hold every possible decimal value.

That means if you cast a decimal that's larger than int.MaxValue you will overflow, and if the decimal is smaller than int.MinValue, it will underflow.

What happens when you under/overflow?  One of two things.  If your build is unchecked (i.e., the CLR doesn't care if you do), your application will continue after the value over/underflows, but the value in the int will not be what you expected.  This can lead to intermittent bugs and may be hard to fix.  You'll end up your application in an unknown state which may result in your application corrupting whatever important data its working on.  Not good.

If your assembly is checked (properties->build->advanced->check for arithmetic overflow/underflow or the /checked compiler option), your code will throw an exception when an under/overflow occurs.  This is probably better than not; however the default for assemblies is not to check for over/underflow.

The real question is "what are you trying to do?"  Without knowing your requirements, nobody can tell you what you **should** do in this case, other than the obvious:  DON'T DO IT.

If you specifically do NOT care, the answers here are valid.  However, you should *communicate* your understanding that an overflow may occur and that it doesn't matter by wrapping your cast code in an **unchecked** block

```
unchecked
{
  // do your conversions that may underflow/overflow here
}
```

That way people coming behind you understand you don't care, and if in the future someone changes your builds to /checked, your code won't break unexpectedly.

**If** all you want to do is drop the fractional portion of the number, leaving the integral part, you can use Math.Truncate.

```
decimal actual = 10.5M;
decimal expected = 10M;
Assert.AreEqual(expected, Math.Truncate(actual));
```

Comment: Though I suspect they're the same thing under the hood if the input is a decimal, I feel more comfortable using Decimal.Truncate than Math.Truncate, since the latter also accepts doubles and thus can be understood to be able to truncate even numbers that are not base 10, as opposed to Decimal.Truncate, which is a true truncation of a base 10 number.

Comment: Unchecked contexts do not apply to decimals; operations on decimals will throw OverflowExceptions regardless.

Answer (score 50):

```
int i = (int)d;
```

will give you the number rounded down.

If you want to round to the nearest even number (i.e. >.5 will round up) you can use

```
int i = (int)Math.Round(d, MidpointRounding.ToEven);
```

In general you can cast between all the numerical types in C#. If there is no information that will be lost during the cast you can do it implicitly:

```
int i = 10;
decimal d = i;
```

though you can still do it explicitly if you wish:

```
int i = 10;
decimal d = (decimal)i;
```

However, if you are going to be losing information through the cast you must do it explicitly (to show you are aware you may be losing information):

```
decimal d = 10.5M;
int i = (int)d;
```

Here you are losing the ".5". This may be fine, but you must be explicit about it and make an explicit cast to show you know you may be losing the information.

Comment: You actually want MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero if you want > *.5 to always round up based on my experience trying out the code above looking at sample output here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.midpointrounding(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_2

Comment: @ElijahLofgren It kinda depends: If you're doing statistics, `ToEven` should prevent statistic drift. If you however operate with chargeable items or money, `AwayFromZero` seems like the right choice.

Answer (score 26):

```
decimal d = 2;
int i = (int) d;
```

This should work just fine.

Comment: Careful, with an explicit conversion information might be lost.

Comment: When converting from decimal to int, information will almost always be lost but I believe that's kinda the point.

Answer (score 18):

```
decimal vIn = 0.0M;
int vOut = Convert.ToInt32(vIn);
```

Here is a very handy convert data type webpage for those of others.
http://www.convertdatatypes.com/Convert-decimal-to-int-in-CSharp.html

Answer (score 8):

`System.Decimal` implements the `IConvertable` interface, which has a `ToInt32()` member.

Does calling `System.Decimal.ToInt32()` work for you?

Comment: From [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb350799(v=vs.110).aspx) : "This API supports the .NET Framework infrastructure and is not intended to be used directly from your code".
Why not use Convert.ToInt32?

Answer (score 8):

Rounding a decimal to the nearest integer

```
decimal a ;
int b = (int)(a + 0.5m);
```

when `a = 49.9`, then `b = 50`

when `a = 49.5`, then `b = 50`

when `a = 49.4`, then `b = 49` etc.

Answer (score 7):

A neat trick for fast rounding is to add .5 before you cast your decimal to an int.

```
decimal d = 10.1m;
d += .5m;
int i = (int)d;
```

Still leaves `i=10`, but

```
decimal d = 10.5m;
d += .5m;
int i = (int)d;
```

Would round up so that `i=11`.

Comment: Why bother doing this when there's Math.Floor and Math.Ceiling?

Comment: At the time, I was fairly new to C# and for some reason I didn't realize these functions existed. It's actually a trick I learned from C/C++, where it was obviously more useful.

Comment: What if the decimal value was e.g. -9.3?

Answer (score 7):

I prefer using [Math.Round](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.round.aspx), [Math.Floor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.floor.aspx), [Math.Ceiling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.ceiling.aspx) or [Math.Truncate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.truncate.aspx) to explicitly set the rounding mode as appropriate.

Note that they all return Decimal as well - since Decimal has a larger range of values than an Int32, so you'll still need to cast (and check for overflow/underflow).

```
 checked {
   int i = (int)Math.Floor(d);
 }
```

Answer (score 7):

decimal `d = 5.5`;

```
int i = decimal.ToInt32(d);// you will get i = 5
```

ref: [link text](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.toint32.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

No answer seems to deal with the OverflowException/UnderflowException that comes from trying to convert a decimal that is outside the range of int.

```
int intValue = (int)Math.Max(int.MinValue, Math.Min(int.MaxValue, decimalValue));
```

This solution will return the maximum or minimum int value possible if the decimal value is outside the int range. You might want to add some rounding with Math.Round, Math.Ceiling or Math.Floor for when the value is inside the int range.

Answer (score 2):

Convert decimal to integer

```
decimal decimalValue=5.00;
int intValue=Convert.ToInt32(decimalValue);
```

Answer (score 1):

I find that the casting operator does not work if you have a boxed decimal (i.e. a decimal value inside an object type).  Convert.ToInt32(decimal as object) works fine in this case.

This situation comes up when retrieving IDENTITY/AUTONUMBER values from the database:

```
SqlCommand foo = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO...; SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()", conn);
int ID = Convert.ToInt32(foo.ExecuteScalar());  // works
int ID = (int)foo.ExecuteScalar();              // throws InvalidCastException
```

See [4.3.2 Unboxing conversions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691159.aspx)

Comment: Adding more to it for reference: that's because you can only unbox to the same original type. Here `SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()` returns `numeric(38, 0)` which translates to `decimal` by .NET. `foo.ExecuteScalar()` returns a `decimal` boxed as `object` which cannot be casted directly to an `int`. `(int)(decimal)foo.ExecuteScalar()` or `Convert.ToInt32(foo.ExecuteScalar())` would work.