# convert from int to double

Tags: c#, .net, casting

I have an integer (representing seconds) which I'm converting to hours by dividing by 3600. I then store the value in a property (type int). If the value contains a decimal point, I convert it by casting. However, when I try to assign the value to the property, I get an error: "Cannot implicitly convert type 'decimal' to 'int'." Here's my code:

```
var p = ((Hours.Duration) / 3600.0);
(Hours.Duration) = p;
```

However,

```
Hours.Duration =  (Hours.Duration) / 3600
```

works fine, and rounds to an `int`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/501090/c-sharp-how-do-i-convert-a-decimal-to-an-int)

Answer (score 2):

```
decimal p = ((Hours.Duration) / 3600);
(Hours.Duration) = p;
```

you are getting error because `p` is decimal and Hours.Duration is integer, You cannot assign decimal to int without explicit casting.

```
(Hours.Duration) = (int)p;
```

If `Hours.Duration` is `integer`, 3600 is also integer, then there will be an integer division, that is your decimal value will be lost. e.g. in integer division `7/2 =3`. If you want the answer to be 3.5, then you need to have atleast one decimal number in the division i.e `7.0/2 = 3.5` OR `7/2.0 = 3.5`.

Comment: if Hours.Duration = 1800, then p = 0.5 ..but how to assign that value to Hours.Duration again. On explicit conversion in line 2 
    Convert.ToDecimal((Hours.Duration)) = p;
The error says, the lhs of an assignment must be a variable, property, indexer.

Comment: You can not store values with decimal in int variable. You need to change type of Hours.Duration. That is you cannot save 0.5 in int variable. @Premanshu

Comment: actually, in the database, we store seconds(int) and display to the user as hours (they may be decimals as well)..Till i was using 1,2 etc for testing.. but on decimal entry it rejects..Anyway many thanks for continuous answering..

Comment: This conversion is actually not possible..And since i was trying these in my model class (MVC)...So did the changes finally in my view...and it works..cheers..

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
Hours.Duration = Convert.ToInt32(p);
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't define p as decimal. And the question is, if you want to include also partial hour (e.g. if the result for 4000/3600 would be 1 or 2). So you can write directly

Hours.Duration /= 3600;

or if you want count also partial hour

Hours.Duration = Hours.Duration / 3600 + ((Hours.Duration % 3600 > 0)?1:0);

or if you want correct rounding up

Hours.Duration = Hours.Duration / 3600 + ((Hours.Duration % 3600 >= 1800)?1:0);

Comment: Thanks @Ivo...since Hours.Duration turn out to be an int, hence adding decimal part would still result in error.Isn't??? Many thanks for the reply though.

Comment: Hours.Duration would be 1, accepted.But what about the decimal part???Ideally 4500 shall result into 
    4500/3600 = 1.25
so where from are we appending the decimal part(900 seconds leftover post division)??? I think we can't assign decimal values to int types after casting.Any more literature would surely help me. Appreciate your concerns.Thanks Ivo

Comment: If you need to show decimal part, you definitely need to change Hours.Duration type. Or think about hours:minutes:seconds format.

Comment: The variable Hours.Duration is a property of type int.

Comment: Extend your structure for integer values DurationH for hours, DurationM for minutes and DurationS for seconds. Then run
`int reminder = Hours.DurationH % 3600;
Hours.DurationH /= 3600;
Hours.DurationM = reminder / 60;
Hours.DurationS = reminder % 60;`
and finally show the result in format hours:minutes:seconds
This is I think the best way.

Comment: Im allowed to display only hours (upto 2 decimals to be precise).

Comment: In that case change Hours.Duration type to decimal and make sure it is correctly formated when shown (something like {0:F2} in the formatting string) .

Comment: Or use Hours.Duration.ToString("F2",Culture.CurrentCulture) with decimal Hours.Duration

Comment: Thanks Ivo...I would sure check it andd let u know of the results... Appreciate your enthusiasm....Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
int vIn = 0;
double vOut = Convert.ToDouble(vIn);
```

Here is a very handy convert data type webpage for those of others: [Convert decimal to int in C#](http://www.convertdatatypes.com/Convert-decimal-to-int-in-CSharp.html)