# How can a decimal format to string in mvc avoiding the last two zero s after the decimal point in mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I rounded the loan amount value. But in my model I have defined the Loan Amount as Decimal. In Grid I need to show it as an Integer (need to  avoid the last two zero's after the point).

For example: it shows as 22.00 if the data saved is 21.50. In the grid I need to display as 22 only - avoiding the zeros after the point.

Code:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LoanAmount)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create Helper method e.g. `DisplayDecimal`

```
public static class HtmlExtensionsView
{
    public static string DisplayDecimal(this HtmlHelper helper, decimal? input)
    {
        // you can do you rouding math here
    }
}
```

then in your .cshtml file you can call (referencing extension's namespace) `@Html.DisplayDecimal(modelItem => item.LoanAmount)`

More information about rounding in C# is available at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3s2d3xkk.aspx

Comment: Regards converting an `decimal` to an `int`, check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/501090/how-do-i-convert-a-decimal-to-an-int-in-c

Answer (score 0):

In your view you can simply add the following:

```
@string.Format("{0:#}", modelItem.LoanAmount)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use DisplayFormat attribute to make it work as per your choice..
Just decorate your property with displayformat and provide appropriate format.

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "YOUR_FORMAT")]
public decimal YourProperName {get;set;}
```