# How can I display decimal data as whole numbers in a DataGridView?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

How can I convert this column into a whole number instead of a decimal?

[image]

Comment: the column type is number

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I convert a decimal to an int in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/501090/how-do-i-convert-a-decimal-to-an-int-in-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After setting the `DataSource` for your `DataGridView`, specify the [numeric format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#NFormatString) of that column:

```
dataGridView1.Columns["age"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "N0";
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm not sure exactly where your code is, but in general you'd say 

    `Convert.ToInt32(age)`