# Why can't I convert an integer into binary with Convert.ToInt32?

Tags: c#

By using that statement I can change my binary value to decimal value by swapping the values but why isn't this statement working for decimal to binary conversion?

```
int decimalVal = 10;
int binaryVal = Convert.ToInt32(decimalVal, 2); // want 1010
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use `Convert.ToInt32(String, Int32)` method to convert binary to integer and `Convert.ToString(Int32, Int32)` method to convert integer to binary.

```cs
string binaryVal = Convert.ToString(decimalVal, 2);
```

To find more information:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.toint32?view=netframework-4.8

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.tostring?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 1):

They are of different byte sizes: https://condor.depaul.edu/sjost/nwdp/notes/cs1/CSDatatypes.htm And you are trying to convert one directly and expect binary while this does not work like that.

This two answers should help you:
[How do I convert a decimal to an int in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/501090/how-do-i-convert-a-decimal-to-an-int-in-c)

And

[Convert integer to binary in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2954962/convert-integer-to-binary-in-c-sharp)

What you will figure out from this two answers is that Covnert.ToInt32 does not have an overload that takes an instance of decimal and converts it to binary. You will need to cast the decimal first to an integer and then you would be able to cast it to binary, For example:

```
decimal value = 8;
int n = Convert.ToInt32(value);

string binary = Convert.ToString(n, 2);
binary.Dump();
```

The output would be: `1000`

This example is tested in Linqpad

Answer (score 1):

```
int decimalVal = 10;
string binary = Convert.ToString(decimalVal, 2);
```

Comment: Hello John, I cant seem what did you edit. Could tell me please?

Comment: I just added 4 spaces before each line so that it was formatted as code. You can see the revision history [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57107643/revisions) (or access it by clicking "edited N minutes ago").

Comment: Aah I forgot to inline the code. Thanks for that anyway.

Comment: why it is not done by Convert.ToInt32